# create multiple custom post using same function

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

in   __construct() function i created two add_action and do_action is like below:

```
class eksoptn
{

function _init()
{

    add_action('post_creater', array($this, 'post_register'), 10, 2); 
    do_action('post_creater', 'slideshow', 'HOmeslide hsow'); 
    do_action('post_creater', 'portfolio', 'porfolio'); 
}

 function post_register($post_slug=null, $postname=null) {


    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x($postname, 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x($postname, 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add '.$postname, 'snack'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add '.$postname),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$postname),
        'new_item' => __('New '.$postname),
        'view_item' => __('View '.$postname),
        'search_items' => __('Search '.$postname),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-generic',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
    ); 

    register_post_type( $post_slug , $args );
}
}

 $eksoptn = new eksoptn; 
 $eksoptn->_init();
```

when i am try above code then showing error like below

```
Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\fresenius\wp-includes\rewrite.php
```

And when i put for loop in register_function then it work fine.
but using do_action showing me erroe
Then what should i do there.

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: ok plaese wait.. @vel

Comment: what is the WP version you are using?

Comment: i am currently using version 4.7.5 @vel

Comment: I think you are not update your full code. you missed to post `register_taxonomy` i think

Comment: @vel i have no need  taxonomy in custom post so i have not used

Comment: replace this code `add_action('post_creater', array($this, 'post_register'), 10, 2); ` with  `add_action('init', array($this, 'post_register'), 10, 2); ` and try. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJVzI.png

Comment: i know this one working, but i want need add multiple post using do_action like. do_action('post_creater', 'slideshow', 'HOmeslide hsow'); 
    do_action('post_creater', 'portfolio', 'porfolio'); 
 do_action('post_creater', 'wervice', 'Service'); 
    do_action('post_creater', 'work', 'Work');